# Automatic write diagram's titles in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, charts, vba

I try to add in a given script some commands in order to automatically update the titles of charts (the charts are produced from the same script provided by Scott Holtzman). 
My questions:
1. How can I escape quotes in order to update the text with given variables (I have read  this can be done with double quotes ""i"" but it is not working)
2. It is possible to write greek characters and how?
3. It is possible to write with indices or lower case letters or subscripts?
4. How can I change the axes labels? I have defined two but I am changing only the y-axis and not the x-axis.

Here is my script (provided by Scott Holtzman) and my comments waht I am trying to do:

```
    Sub MakeCharts()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Tabelle1")
    Dim dthArray() As Variant
    Dim kxArray() As Variant
    Dim text1 As String
    Dim text2 As String
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    i = 1
    j = 1

' Strings for the charts'titles:
    dthArray() = Array("0", "0,5", "1", "5", "10")
    kxArray() = Array("0", "0,01", "1", "5")

    For y = 1 To 259 Step 65
    For x = 1 To 259 Step 13

        ws.Shapes.AddChart.Select

        With ActiveChart

            .ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers

            Dim k As Integer

            For k = 1 To 13

                .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
                .SeriesCollection(k).Name = ws.Cells(x, k + 1)
                .SeriesCollection(k).XValues = ws.Range(ws.Cells(x + 1, k + 1), ws.Cells(x + 11, k + 1))
                .SeriesCollection(k).Values = ws.Range(ws.Cells(x + 1, 1), ws.Cells(x + 11, 1))
                .HasTitle = True


            Next

            .ApplyLayout (1)

            Dim sName As String
            sName = Replace(.Name, ws.Name & " ", "")
            'Updating String for chart's title
            text1 = dthArray(i)
            text2 = kxArray(j)

            ' Write chart's title
            .ChartTitle.Text = "dth=""text1""" & "  " & "dx = ""text2"""
            'sigma should be in greek and t as subscript
            .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "sigmat/a"
            .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "eta=y/H"

        End With

        With ActiveSheet.Shapes(sName)
            .IncrementLeft 300
            .IncrementTop x * 20
        End With
    i = i + 1
    Next
    j = j + 1
    Next
    End Sub
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: to answer first question: change `.ChartTitle.Text = "dth=""text1""" & "  " & "dx = ""text2"""` to `.ChartTitle.Text = "dth=""" & text1 & """  dx = """ & text2 & """`

Comment: @Scott Holtzman That works, thank you!

Comment: for questions 3 and 4, use the macro recorder while doing it manually to get the syntax (it's all possible). I imagine the greek is possible too, if you have the greek characters, you can record a macro as you do that manually as well.

Comment: @Scott Holtzman: may you know how can I avoid the quotes at the title? They apear there either way I write my array (as variant, string or with split).

Comment: if you don't want quotes at all, write this: = `"dth = " & text1 & " dx = " & text2`

Comment: For Greek characters one has to use this form: ChrW(952) for theta

Comment: For subscripts this command: Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(2, 1).Font.BaselineOffset = - _
            0.25

Comment: For Greek characters one has to use this form: ChrW(952) for theta  for rest greek letters here http://ancienthistory.about.com/od/greeklanguage/a/ASCIIGreek.htm